# Multiple Providers as one parameter in angular.module.config

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I'm trying to pass one Provider to the angular.module().config() i do the following:

```
angular.module('login', ['login.filters', 'login.services', 'login.directives', 'login.controllers']).
    config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
        ...
    }]);
```

and it works. When I'm trying to pass multiple providers to the config() i do the following:

```
angular.module('login', ['login.filters', 'login.services', 'login.directives', 'login.controllers']).
    config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        ...
    });
```

And it works as well. But why I can't do this?:

```
angular.module('login', ['login.filters', 'login.services', 'login.directives', 'login.controllers']).
    config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        ...
    }]);
```

Comment: Should work fine...what error do you get?

Comment: `$locationProvider` is undefined